# Not able to search installed Apps anymore

Tags: iphone, applications, search

I use iphone 6s. whenever I need to run an app on iphone, I just search for the app. (using flashlight).

Off late I have noticed that whenever I search for an app, it doesn't show the installed app anymore.

I am pretty sure that this earlier the search on iphone used to show installed apps as part of search results.

Now it only shows
* suggested websites
* wikipedia
* twitter
* itunes store

Why did this behavior change?

Comment: If you check "Settings -> General -> Spotlight Search" on your phone are all the buttons green?

Comment: yes I checked. everything is green there. but still when I search, it shows the "app store" and then "suggested websites" but doesn't show installed apps. Earlier it used to show... now something changed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by reinstalling IOS on my iphone. It wasn't a very good solution, but sadly nothing else worked for me.

Apple is not very different from Microsoft after all.